# Viewing the CIL of a portable executable

Tags: .net, exe, cil

What is a good program to get a nice, human readable form of the CLI of a portable executable file? I don't want a full disassembler because I'd like to learn how they work (or, in my case, not work).

Comment: Do you mean something that would just dump all streams, metadata tables etc in more-or-less human-readable form?

Comment: I was looking for something where I could easily browse trough the various classes, instead of producing a 100k lines file :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I recommend [reflector](http://www.red-gate.com/products/reflector/).

It can show you IL, C# and a lot more.

[**edited**]
Since reflector is not free anymore I am using [ILSpy](http://wiki.sharpdevelop.net/ILSpy.ashx)
[/**edited**]

Best

Adriano

Answer (score 3):

You should be to use [ILDASM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7dy01k1(VS.80).aspx) to extract the IL

```
ildasm.exe MyProgram.exe /out=MyProgram.il
```